# Why Does My Mesh Move When Attaching Armature?

Tags: rigging, armature, bones

I have a mesh and I have an armature that I placed within the mesh. I select the mesh, I select the armature whilst holding shift, then I do a Ctrl+P to attach the armature. I click Armature Deform with Automatic Weights, and suddenly my entire mesh decides it needs to be somewhere else and moves to some new location--the bones are no longer within as they remain where they were. What gives? Why is my mesh moving away from the bones?

Comment: perhaps you could share your file because it's hard to tell

Comment: Well... it might have something to do with me having already attached it... I didn't realize I had already done it before I saved last week. Still not sure why that makes it jump to some new location though...

Comment: Could you upload your blend file file here blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com so I can try to help you?

Comment: @Tak, I can't... every time I try to upload, it says I need to accept the terms and conditions, but the checkbox is already checked. Using Chrome. IE doesn't even work at all. Won't open browse and can't drag-drop.

Comment: @CodeMonkey you can upload it to http://pasteall.org/blend/ send me the link and I will upload it myself here

Comment: @Tak Okay, looks like that worked. No laughing at my crappy skills, now ;-). Also, remember that it is already attached as my comment above stated, but I imagine that redoing it is allowed and shouldn't move my mesh around, right? It should just re-weight it? And thanks! http://pasteall.org/blend/index.php?id=49859

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To fix this follow the below steps:

1- Select your armature and hit <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>

2- Hit Apply Rotation

3- Do step 1 again and hit Apply Scale then again and Apply Location

4- Select your mesh and do steps from 1-3 again.

5- Voila, it will work :)

Comment: Thanks! I would love to understand why this works. There were "unapplied" rotations? What does that actually mean? With this same model, I'm pulling it into Unity and it's not behaving like my other models. I set him up to "face" the Z axis, but when I pull him into Unity, he faces the Y axis. All my other models would face whatever axis I set it to face which is why all my blender models are facing "up" despite how weird that is. So why is this guy being different? Something to do with the mystical rotations and positions that I'm not understanding?

Comment: Ah, nevermind about the Unity part. The armature suddenly had a rotation on it that wasn't there before which did indeed flip the whole character. So that makes sense now. Still not quite sure what the "applying" thing means though from Blender's perspective.

Comment: @CodeMonkey an explanation can be found here https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/editors/3dview/object/editing/transform/clear_apply.html

Comment: It changes point of orgin of an object to 0,0,0. Analogous rotation, scale. While exporting out of blender you have options: which axis to face forward and front.