# Model is incredibly broken after loading file

Tags: modeling, rigging

[image]

So i was working on a model and following this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=srpOeu9UUBU and then saved and quit. The next day I loaded the file and the model now looks like this. What did I do to break it, and can i fix it?

Comment: Hello please share your file so that we can see what's the problem: https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: Try [this](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/111920/why-does-my-mesh-move-when-attaching-armature?rq=1) answer.